# No iMessage since 8.4 update

Tags: ios, messages

I downloaded iOS 8.4 on my iPad and now I can't open Message nor can i open them in the setting menu. In addition, I can't scroll through the settings menu once it's opened. I have rebooted and reset network settings. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The settings menu issue happens to my iPad when it is critically short on disk space. In those cases, I have to delete something (an app, or a video) and reboot the iPad to get it to work.